# Fixing Presence of Load balancer detected issue

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cloudflare

I have a setup with Amazon EC2 running my webapp while the domain hosted at cloudflare. I dont have any kind of Load balancer setup in my infra. Yet when we run the security test at Qualys, the report showed us Severity 1 vulnerability as "**Presence of a Load-Balancing Device Detected**".

The good thing about the report is that it also mentioned about how to fix this issue. The following snippet is the part of the report

```
THREAT :
The service detected a load-balancing device in front of your Web servers. This information can provide an attacker with additional information about your network.
Different techniques were used to detect the presence of a load-balancing device, including HTTP header analysis and analysis of IP Time-T o-Live (TTL) values, IP Identification (ID) values, and TCP Initial Sequence Numbers (ISN). The actual technique(s) responsible for the detection can be seen in the Result section.
The exact number of Web servers behind a load balancer is difficult to determine, so the number reported here may not be accurate. Furthermore, Netscape Enterprise Server Version 3.6 is known to display an erroneous "Date:" field in the HTTP header when the server receives a lot of requests. This makes it difficult for the service to determine if there is a load-balancing device present by analyzing the HTTP headers. Also, the result given by the analysis of IP ID and TCP ISN values may vary due to different network conditions when the scan was performed.

IMP ACT :
By exploiting this vulnerability, an intruder could use this information in conjunction with other pieces of information to craft sophisticated attacks against your network.
Note also that if the Web servers behind the load balancer are not identical, the scan results for the HTTP vulnerabilities may vary from one scan to another .

SOLUTION:
To prevent the detection of the presence of a load-balancing device based on HTTP header analysis, you should use Network-Time-Protocol (NTP) to synchronize the clocks on all of your hosts (at least those in the DMZ).
To prevent detection by analyzing IP TTL values, IP ID values, and TCP ISN values, you may use hosts with a TCP/IP implementation that generates randomized numbers for these values. However, most operating systems available today do not come with such a TCP/IP implementation.

COMPLIANCE: Not Applicable

EXPLOIT ABILITY :
There is no exploitability information for this vulnerability.

ASSOCIATED MALWARE:
There is no malware information for this vulnerability.

RESULTS:
Number of web servers behind load balancer: 100 - based on HTTP headers
```

The problem with this report and the solution is that I dont have any load balancer setup so I'm unable to synchronize my server clock(what should i synchronize it with if there isn't any load balancer/hosts for me to set up NTP on it)

Comment: This looks like a nonsense detection of a nonexistent vulnerability. CloudFlare uses load balancers in its infrastructure, so if your site is actually using CloudFlare (for more than just DNS -- you didn't specifically say) then your site is using *their* load balancers.  The explanation *"Number of web servers behind load balancer: 100 - based on HTTP header"* doesn't give you any useful information.

Comment: Yes we're using Origin SSL certs from Cloudflare. Any way to get rid of this vulnerability?

Comment: I am strongly inclined to insist that this is an entirely false detection -- not a genuine vulnerability -- and thus a meaningless report.